# Getting SQS retrieveMessages resolved in Node

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am getting a few behaviors I didn't expect when running the example code from the AWS SDK for SQS.

I have the following code which takes a queue URL.

```
const getMessage = url => {
  return sqs.receiveMessage(
    {
      QueueUrl: url
    },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      } else {
        // console.log(data);
        if (data.Messages) {
          const msg = JSON.parse(data.Messages[0].Body);
          console.log("--");
          return msg
        } else {
          console.log("no messages found");
          return {};
        }
      }
    }
  );
};

const messages = await getMessage(<QUEUE_URL>);
console.log('this statement runs before the other console statements')
```

I understand from the documentation here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#receiveMessage-property

That the function `recieveMessage` returns a request.  But I don't understand why the console statement after the function call is being run before the console.log within the callback since I am awaiting its response.

The order of the logs makes me think I am missing something with the asynchronous nature of the operation and the wrapper function.

Has anyone run into this before?  I have been going in circles on this one for awhile and can't seem to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to return Promise in order to await its result

```
 const getMessage = url => {
  return sqs.receiveMessage(
    {
      QueueUrl: url
    })
     .promise()
     .then(data=>{
      // process data here
     })
     .catch(e=>{
     // process error here
     })
```